# jquery & x-tmpl

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates, blueimp

I am using blueimp uploader in my code and I want to modify the code little bit. Here is the part of the code I want to modify.

```
    <script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
        {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
              <tr class="template-download fade">
                  {% if (file.error) { %}
        <td></td>
        <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
        <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
        <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">{%=locale.fileupload.error%}</span> {%=locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error%}</td>
    {% } else { %}
        <td class="preview">{% if (file.thumbnail_url) { %}
            <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="gallery" download="{%=file.name%}"><img src="{%=file.thumbnail_url%}"></a>
        {% } %}</td>
        <td class="name">
            <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="{%=file.thumbnail_url&&'gallery'%}" download="{%=file.name%}">{%=file.name%}</a>
        </td>
        <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
    {% } %}
    <td class="delete">
         <button class="btn btn-danger" data-type="{%=file.delete_type%}" data-url="{%=file.delete_url%}">
            <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
            <span>{%=locale.fileupload.destroy%}</span>
        </button>
        <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" id="imagename" name="imagename" value="{%=file.name%}"/>

    </td>
</tr>
{% } %}
```

I added a hidden input at the very end of the code as:

```
 <input type="hidden" id="imagename" name="imagename" value="{%=file.name%}"/>
```

What I want to do is, whenever I upload an image I want to get its name in order to store into the the database. The thing is I am not able to get a unique name for the hidden inputs. Suppose, I upload three images every hidden fields' name becomes the same.

I tired to use the vaiable "i",which is in the for loop, in order to concatinate the like "imagename+i" but could not do it.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

did you try
`id="imagename-{%=i}"`

Comment: i am sorry my mistake. It should be `id="imagename-{%=i%}"`

Answer (score 0):

The ***fileuploadsubmit*** bind [here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-form-data#setting-formdata-on-upload-start-for-each-individual-file-upload) should do the trick.